Wrapper to monitor CPU and memory usage for a command line without knowing its duration in advance
This great (in my opinion) answer on Super User provides a solution to track CPU and memory usage of a command line. It is great, however, you need to know in advance the duration of your command line. How could you perform the same without knowing it in advance?
It is suggested in the mentioned answer that a wrapper would do the trick!

It looks like the script in the linked answer has since been updated to include automatically tracking duration. I think this question can be closed
